# How I can run jscpd from grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I build my project via grunt. I want to add grunt-jscpd task there. I couldn't run it via grunt. I created next .cpd.yaml file in the same directory where placed Gruntfile.js:

```
#.cpd.yaml
path:
  - src/main/webapp/js/accounts/
languages:
  - javascript
exclude:
  - "**/node_modules/**"
```

When I run next commant "jscpd --languages js" from the directory where placed Gruntfile.js, jscpd works correctly and I see result:

```
info:    Files search time: duration=58ms
info:    Scaning 74 files for duplicates...
info:    Scaning for duplicates time: duration=1674ms
info:    Scaning... done!

info:    Start report generation...

info:    Found 7 exact clones with 120 duplicated lines in 10 files
...
3.54% (120 lines) duplicated lines out of 3393 total lines of code.
```

But when I run it via grunt, jscpd doesn't check my code (I run "grunt jscpd" command).
Here result of it:

```
Running "jscpd:js" (jscpd) task
[Function: jscpd]
Used config from ../cm-html/.cpd.yaml
Scaning... done!

Found 0 exact clones with 0 duplicated lines in 0 files


100.00% (0 lines) duplicated lines out of 0 total lines of code.
```

Here my grunt task:

```
jscpd: {
        js: {
            path: '../cm-html',
            exclude: ['../cm-html/src/main/webapp/js/lib/**']
        }
    },
```

How I can run it via grunt correctly?

Comment: Where is your JS stored? Try setting the path to that folder directly (and add the trailing `/`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for grunt - https://github.com/mazerte/grunt-jscpd

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jscpd: {
    javascript: {
      path: 'lib/js/'
    }
  }
}
```